# Make table views in ModelBuilder with Iterator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table, iterator

I'm trying to use the model as shown in the image to get 300 tables for the 300 points in the input feature class. I can get 300 viewshed rasters but can only get the table of the last point.

It seems the model did create 300 tables, however, each table was named the same (vshed_0_View) even though I had put the "_%n%" in the output name, so the created tables were always overwritten by the next one.

I had uncheck "Intermediate" for vshed_%n% so the obtained viewshed rasters were not deleted.

I don't know what caused the problem. Does "Make table view" not work with Iterator? Are there any other ways to avoid being overwritten? Many Thanks![image]

Comment: Could you try parsing out the n so it's separate ? So something like `"vshed" + "%n" `

Comment: I think the "_%n%" is OK. I've found the problem: "If you are using %n% in the output name of a model parameter, and the model is run from its tool dialog box in ArcMap or ArcCatalog, the iteration number of the application is substituted for %n%. Since the iteration number %n% of the application is 0, the model tool will fail after one iteration with the error message "ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Tool). Parameters are not valid." In this case, you must either change the variable so that it is not a model parameter or remove %n% from the output name."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the table view permanent by using [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) and then try the `%n%` system variable.

Alternatively, call the `Value` variable:

```
vshed_%Value%_View
```

Additional Information:

- [A quick tour of using inline variable substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000001t000000)
- [Examples of in-line variable substitution with ModelBuilder system
  variables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_in_line_variable_substitution_with_ModelBuilder_system_variables/002w00000060000000/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I found it in your link that "If you are using %n% in the output name of a model parameter, and the model is run from its tool dialog box in ArcMap or ArcCatalog, the iteration number of the application is substituted for %n%. Since the iteration number %n% of the application is 0, the model tool will fail after one iteration with the error message "ERROR 000622....." and I think this caused the problem. And also many thanks for mentioning Table to Table, it solved another problem.